# Store Logging information to oracle database

Tags: java, log4j, logging, java.util.logging

I have currently implemented a java swing application. In that application I have used java.util.logging to log things in to a text file. But It is difficult to go through the text file since the file is very big.

So I'm thinking to store logging information in to a oracle database(Which i am using for the application) and provide swing interface to access that table. So I will be able search that table for certain logging levels like  INFO and SEVERE. Is there way to do that using java util package or using Log4j. Pls help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at these appenders: `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender` or an improved version [`org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCAppender`](http://www.dankomannhaupt.de/projects/).

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own Appender by extending the `org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton`. You can make him configurable for several data storages and define how to split up the [LoggingEvent](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html) where you can get the seperated informations as line-number, class-name, message, logger-severity etc.

```
public class StorageBasedAppender
    extends AppenderSkeleton
{
    [...]

    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event)
    {
        // Write to your database or other storages
    }
}
```

You could enhance this class by making it configurable and more. If you don't need somewhat specific, regardings to the other questions make use of the [JDBCAppenderConfiguration](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/JDBCAppenderConfiguration). Which can be configured easily

```
<appender name="jdbcAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender"> 
    <param name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@sd1.hbs.edu:1521:sc1" /> 
    <param name="Driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" /> 
    <param name="User" value="user" /> 
    <param name="Password" value="password" /> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
          value="INSERT INTO LOGGING_SAMPLES_TEST 
          (log_date, log_level, location, message) 
          VALUES ( '%d{ISO8601}','%p', '%C;%L', '%m' )" 
        /> 
    </layout> 
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a JDBC Log4j Appender.

Check out [Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm) or [Apache Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/JDBCAppenderConfiguration)

You might need to change your configuration accordingly whether you use .properties or .xml.